# How to set the Textview visibility in an onClick listener?

Tags: java, android-studio, textview, onclicklistener

first sorry for my english and my knowledge, I'm a french beginner.

I would like to set the visibility of each of my four Textview according to four buttons (one button for one Textview). So I've the next code, but when I click on the button, the apps is closing. I'm watching the debug, but I don't understand what's not working.

Thank you for all your helps !

````
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TextView mWhoAreWeTextView1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.who_are_we_text_1);
        TextView mOurSchoolTextView1 = v.findViewById(R.id.our_school_text_1);
        TextView mWhatDoWeDoTextView1 = v.findViewById(R.id.what_do_we_do_text_1);
        TextView mComeInTextView1 = v.findViewById(R.id.come_in_text_1);

        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.about_part_1:
                if (mWhoAreWeTextView1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                    mWhoAreWeTextView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else {
                    mWhoAreWeTextView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            case R.id.about_part_2:
                break;

            case R.id.about_part_3:
                break;

            case R.id.about_part_4:
                break;
        }```
````

Comment: @KishanMaurya can you help me please ?

Comment: Can you show the erroe that you get?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to know that every initialize of View better to do in the `onCreate` function
2. Make sure you are implementing `View.OnClickListener`
3. You are using `View.GONE` that removing the textview from the screen and not only stop from displaying the textview
   To do that you need to use `View.INVISIVLE`
4. Your code is ok (the code that check the visibility of the view) but you forgot to do the most important part and it's to initializing and calling the buttons like this for example

```
Button button1example = findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1example.setOnClickListener(this);
```